# How to integrate native app(android) with phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova

I have **my android app** and now I want to combine it with **my phonegap app** in android studio.
For that, I have created **new phonegap demo app** from Terminal. And import that project into android studio.
Then Paste "components,css and js" folders from **my phonegap app** to new demo app in "assets" folder.
And also paste .java and .xml file from **my android app** in respective folders.
I have used angularjs.
Now, I want to access variables from .java pages into .js pages.
Is there any solution for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own plugin, to query Java data from JavaScript. Check this [plugin development guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_plugin.md.html#Android%20Plugins). The inverse, accessing JavaScript data from Java code is also possible if you cache a `CallbackContext` in a static variable.